# How can I use javascript/jquery to get my floating icon to know which list item it is in front of?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggable floating icon that you can drag in front of these big square list items. I put the list behind the icon in css with

```
li{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Is there any way that the floating icon, made with anime-js, can figure out which list item it is in front of?

Comment: please elaborate your problem and provide relative code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by finding positions with [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). This is by using collision detection. If you instead want to do something on drag & drop of cursor, use the [drag and drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) instead.

```js
function findElementBehindCursor(cursor, elements) {
  var cursorBoundingBox = cursor.getBoundingClientRect(),
    overlapped;
  overlapped = [...elements].filter(e => isInside(e.getBoundingClientRect(), cursorBoundingBox));
  return overlapped;
}

function isInside(eBounds, cBounds) {
  return eBounds.top < cBounds.top && eBounds.right > cBounds.right && eBounds.bottom > cBounds.bottom && eBounds.left < cBounds.left;
}

function runExample() {
  var cursorEle = document.getElementById('draghandle');
  var liElements = document.getElementById('boxlist').children;
  var results = findElementBehindCursor(cursorEle, liElements);

  results.forEach(e => e.style.backgroundColor = 'green');
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#boxlist li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
}
#draghandle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
button {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runExample()">Click to find element behind yellow cursor</button>
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="boxlist">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="draghandle">
  </div>
</div>
```